# merge multiple videos and audios with ffmpeg

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, video-processing

I have used the program **youtube-dl** to download a Youtube playlist, i have chosen to download videos and audios separately, i have now a folder full of videos with their corresponding audios that i wish to merge together with ffmpeg.

I need to do this using a batch script but the problem is that youtube-dl added aleatory letters after the original file's title so the videos doesn't have the same name as their corresponding audio, file names looks like this:

```
First title in the playlist 5J34JG.mp4
First title in the playlist H3826D.webm
Second title in the playlist 3748JD.mp4
Second title in the playlist 6SHJFZ.webm
```

How to merge these multiple video/audio files using windows batch script and ffmpeg ?

Edit: I forgot to mention that the .webm files are the audio files and that i have multiple files i can't rename them one by one.

Comment: Those suffixes aren't random - they are the YT id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "outdir=muxed"
if not exist "%outdir%" md "%outdir%" || exit /b 1

:: Get each mp4 file and call the label to mux with webm file.
for %%A in (*.mp4) do call :mux "%%~A"
exit /b

:mux
setlocal
set "videofile=%~1"
set "name=%~n1"

:: Last token of the name is the pattern to remove.
for %%A in (%name:-=- %) do set "pattern=-%%~A"

:: Remove the pattern from the name.
call set "name=%%name:%pattern%=%%"

:: Get the webm filename.
for %%A in ("%name%-*.webm") do set "audiofile=%%~A"

:: Mux if webm file exist and output file does not exist.
if exist "%audiofile%" if not exist "%outdir%\%name%.mp4" (
    ffmpeg -i "%videofile%" -i "%audiofile%" -c copy "%outdir%\%name%.mkv"
)
exit /b
```

The script will 1st make the output directory to save mp4
files so that the output will not become input.

The main `for` loop will get each mp4 filename. The `:mux`
label is called with the mp4 filename as an argument.

The variable `videofile` stores the mp4 filename and
variable `name` stores just the name without extension.

The last token of `name` will be the *YTID* pattern while a
`for` loop will set the last token to `pattern`.

The `call set` will substitute the pattern with "" from the
name. This will give a name that can used with a wildcard to
find the webm filename. A `for` loop will get the webm
filename.

If the destination does exist and not the output file, then
ffmpeg will mux the 2 files into an output file.

Output file container format is mkv.

Comment: I tried to run the batch file but i got error `'■@' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. `, should i put the media files in the ffmpeg folder ? a detail i didn't notice is that file names and the random letters added to them are attached by a dash (-), `First title in the playlist-5J34JG.mp4` i hope this will not affect your script, thanks

Comment: The box character seems to Extended ASCII `A6` which I do not know where that comes from. Extended ASCII can be a problem so try to avoid. The `@` is from the `@echo off` which is OK. Save as new file and ensure ANSI or utf-8 with no BOM. Adjust code for dash by substitute `-` with `- ` to get the pattern. The script will work in the current folder which is where the *mp4* and *webm* files are.

Comment: I executed the last updated script from your post (saved with ANSI encoding) it runs perfectly and works in a correct way but i had to change the .mp4 output to .mkv otherwise ffmpeg gives error and made empty mp4 files. I also run your fist version of the script to files without dash and it works, but if some files have the same title the script ask me to replace or ignore file writing, i ended with 90% of the files converted successfully because some of them have the same titles.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this script solved my problem it's really useful to know how to write batch scripts like this, it saves lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was needing to do something similar, I am posting my shorter code to help others out.

This is for in a subfolder

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%f IN ('dir /b /s F2M\*.mp4') DO ffmpeg -i "%%~dpnxf" -i "%%~dpnf.m4a" -c:v copy -c:a aac -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 "F2M\%%~nf-clean.mp4"
```

This is for if you're doing it in the same directory

```
for %%f in (*.mkv) do ffmpeg -i "%%~dpnxf" -i "%%~dpnf.m4a" -c:v copy -c:a copy -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -shortest "%%~nf-remux.mp4"
```

This is if ffmpeg is not in the same folder

```
set ffmpeg=C:\ffmpeg.exe
for %%a in (*.mkv) do "%ffmpeg%" -i "%%~dpnxf"  -i "%%~dpnf.m4a" -c:v copy -c:a copy  -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -shortest "%%~nf-remux.mp4"
```

Just example codes, not specifically formatted for the OP. Use with caution.